# Finding missing brace in given string

Tags: javascript

I came across a question, in which we had to find a missing curly brace in a given string. To be a valid string, each opening brace should have a closing brace.

The input string will be like this(this is valid):

```
    var validInput = 
   `{
       {
         {
         }
       }
    }

    {
    }

    {
      {
      } 
    }`

var invalidInput =
`
{
  {
  }
}

{
//missing a closing brace here

{
}

`
```

I tried looping through each character in the string and I maintained 2 arrays, one for opening brace and another closing brace. I kept pushing the braces in respective arrays within the loop. With this, I could find out if given string is valid(if length of both arrays are equal). But I cannot figure out the location or index of the missing brace. Kindly let me know how can this be achieved.

Code for reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lzqodfk4/1/

Comment: You cannot know for certain. The missing brace in your example could be at the very end. Or do you want to infer it from whitespace?

Comment: You should be able to figure out the *unmatched* brace with what you're already doing, e.g. the first one in `{ { }`. You can't really know whether the correct string is supposed to be `{ } { }` or `{ { } }`.

Comment: White space is not considered here. The var value will be `var invalidInput = "{{}}{}}";`

Comment: What do you mean by "index of missing brace"? Can you share the sample output format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since whitespace is not considered, this is simply not possible. Take for instance

```
{{}
```

is the third or the last bracket missing? You can't really tell. In this example, though, the result of "restoring" such brace will be the same:

```
{{}}
```

However, here's an example where not only you can't tell where the brace is missing, but also there are different ways to restore it:

```
{{}{{}}
```

Which may be turned into either

```
{{}}{{}}
```

or

```
{{}{{}}}
```

When this happens? Is there some non-trivial situations where you are still able to restore the brace (which is less than find its original position)?

Actually, the only thing that limits you when you're guessing where to put the missing brace is – you can't have more closing braces than opening ones before each position. So the only situation where restoring can be done for certain is when the missing brace is when you have a non-broken sequence followed by a number of opening braces and then closing braces (1 less):

```
{}{}{{}}{{{{ }}}
        *   ^^^^ put it on any of these positions
```

If you put anything non-trivial into the sequence starting from `*`, like

```
{{}{{{ }}}
```

or

```
{{{{ }}}{}
```

restoring is ambiguous.

In other words, if there are points where

```
number_of_opening_braces - number_of_closing_braces == 0,
```

you may be sure that the problem is ahead, not behind (if the closing one is missing), but nothing more.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Highly appreciated. I was wondering if we could catch the opening or closing, based on the logic similar to this one:
http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html

Comment: If there are only brackets, there's nothing more you can do. In your example, there are also assignments, so you can use what I have explained above to test each interval *between* assignments individually. If there's something inside braces, you can do more (but you also loose the help of intervals between assigments if assignments can be inside brace pairs). So if this answers your question, consider upvoting/accepting; otherwise edit your question and provide more context. Best regards